# ng-repeat only on inner elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I find this problem with ng-repeat that the tag where it is used is also gets repeated, how to repeat only the elements inside it?

```
<div class="accordions" ng-repeat="event in eventsData">
                        <!-- content-title -->
                        <div class="content-title active">Donec mollis magna quis urna convallis, quis faucibus sem vestibulum. Sed vehicula suscipit lacus</div>
                        <!--/content-title -->
                        <!-- accordions content -->
                        <div class="content">Donec sollicitudin lacus in felis luctus blandit. Ut hendrerit mattis justo at suscipit. Vivamus orci urna, ornare vitae tellus in, condimentum imperdiet eros. Maecenas accumsan, massa nec vulputate congue, dolor erat ullamcorper dolor, ac aliquam eros sem in dui. In eu sagittis metus. Proin consectetur suscipit dui sed euismod. Nam non metus in est vehicula vestibulum et vel neque.</div>
                        <!--/accordions content -->
                        <!-- content-title -->
                        <div class="content-title">Sed vehicula suscipit lacus, eget cursus justo aliquet in. Etiam aliquet vel ipsum ultrices auctor</div>
                        <!--/content-title -->
                        <!-- accordions content -->
                        <div class="content">Donec sollicitudin lacus in felis luctus blandit. Ut hendrerit mattis justo at suscipit. Vivamus orci urna, ornare vitae tellus in, condimentum imperdiet eros. Maecenas accumsan, massa nec vulputate congue, dolor erat ullamcorper dolor, ac aliquam eros sem in dui. In eu sagittis metus. Proin consectetur suscipit dui sed euismod. Nam non metus in est vehicula vestibulum et vel neque.</div>
                        <!--/accordions content -->
</div>
```

Comment: without wrapping up the title and content in a div. is there any way?

Comment: oh, you need to generate 4 elements without anything between the wrapper and the elements?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If it is a simple list of events, just use `ng-repeat` once on element with `content-title` class, also wrap `content` class element in `content-title` class element.

Comment: yes, i want to repeat only the content-title and content without wrapping them up also that, they have to be in order, `content-title` and `content` should come alternatively

Comment: @PrateekGupta that doesn't work, because the accordion doesn't expect a wrapper, I gather.

Comment: exactly, @ven, you got the point.

Comment: @VallabhRao then see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS has a feature for that: `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`. They allow you to avoid a wrapper altogether, because they don't incur nesting.

```
<div class="accordions"> <!-- !! No repeat here -->
  <div class="content-title active"
     ng-repeat-start="event in eventsData"
  >Donec mollis magna quis urna convallis, quis faucibus sem vestibulum. Sed vehicula suscipit lacus</div>
  <div class="content">Donec sollicitudin lacus in felis luctus blandit. Ut hendrerit mattis justo at suscipit. Vivamus orci urna, ornare vitae tellus in, condimentum imperdiet eros. Maecenas accumsan, massa nec vulputate congue, dolor erat ullamcorper dolor, ac aliquam eros sem in dui. In eu sagittis metus. Proin consectetur suscipit dui sed euismod. Nam non metus in est vehicula vestibulum et vel neque.</div>
  <div class="content-title">Sed vehicula suscipit lacus, eget cursus justo aliquet in. Etiam aliquet vel ipsum ultrices auctor</div>
  <div class="content"
    ng-repeat-end
  >Donec sollicitudin lacus in felis luctus blandit. Ut hendrerit mattis justo at suscipit. Vivamus orci urna, ornare vitae tellus in, condimentum imperdiet eros. Maecenas accumsan, massa nec vulputate congue, dolor erat ullamcorper dolor, ac aliquam eros sem in dui. In eu sagittis metus. Proin consectetur suscipit dui sed euismod. Nam non metus in est vehicula vestibulum et vel neque.</div>
</div>
```

The repeat will be active starting from the element that has the `ng-repeat-start="..."`, up to the element that has the `ng-repeat-end`.

[See the `ngRepeat` docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/docs/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat).

Comment: it might be out of the topic, but, i think, accordions doesn't work if i do it this way, or do they? any idea?

Comment: You'll probably want a CSS-only accordion if possible. Otherwise, use some AngularJS directive. That way you're sure the accordion is updated when `eventsData` is updated.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that class `content-title` and `content` have to be repeated over `eventsData`.

Do this,

```
<div class="accordions">
    <div class="wrapper" ng-repeat = "event in eventsData">
                        <!-- content-title -->
                        <div class="content-title active">Donec mollis magna quis urna convallis, quis faucibus sem vestibulum. Sed vehicula suscipit lacus</div>
                        <!--/content-title -->
                        <!-- accordions content -->
                        <div class="content">Donec sollicitudin lacus in felis luctus blandit. Ut hendrerit mattis justo at suscipit. Vivamus orci urna, ornare vitae tellus in, condimentum imperdiet eros. Maecenas accumsan, massa nec vulputate congue, dolor erat ullamcorper dolor, ac aliquam eros sem in dui. In eu sagittis metus. Proin consectetur suscipit dui sed euismod. Nam non metus in est vehicula vestibulum et vel neque.</div>
    </div>                           
</div>
```

Comment: The question asks to **only repeat the elements inside**. No wrapper.

Comment: @Ven I never said, this is the only solution. This is one of the solutions though.

Comment: The question asks you not to do that.